# Is there an equivalent for this trigger in stored procedures

Tags: mysql

I've been using this MySQL trigger on a dedicated server, so every time a table is updated, it calculates a new sum and updates another table:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_rep_points AFTER INSERT ON users_reputation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE new_total INT(10);
SELECT SUM(rep_points) INTO new_total FROM users_reputation
WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
UPDATE users SET rep_total = new_total WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

I now need to use this on a shared hosting environment, but unfortunately, due to security precautions, I cannot have SUPER USER privileges in a shared environment, which is required for triggers. I don't understand this. I think everybody should be able to use triggers.

I'm not that clued up on stored procedures, in-fact I'm useless, but I'm wondering if this query can be executed using one and if so, can anybody can give me any pointers?

Comment: Sorry, you will not able to use your code. TRIGGER, STORED PROCEDURE and FUNCTION need SUPER USER account to be created and executed.

Comment: @sdespont: According to my hosting support: "Deterministic stored procedures/routines are allowed. Stored functions and triggers are not allowed".

Answer (score 0):

The person who wrote the trigger obviously has very limited SQL skills - the whole body can be expressed as a simple query:

```
UPDATE users SET
rep_total = (SELECT SUM(rep_points) 
    FROM users_reputation 
    WHERE user_id = users.user_id)
WHERE user_id = ?; -- "?" is NEW.user_id inside the trigger. You must provide it
```

You don't need a stored procedure - just run this query.

Comment: Apparently, the reason a trigger was used was because there are approximately 60m rows in `users_reputation` and it was meant to speed up getting the SUM and to delete points if needed. Does your answer still apply to this situation?

Comment: After reading about triggers/stored procedures, I'm not sure your answer is correct. Having a trigger/stored procedure on a table with 60 million rows, to update another table with a SUM, is surely quicker than running your query that has to count first, then update? Using a trigger allows me to use one quick INSERT query. Can you please confirm your statement is correct still?

Comment: My statement is "correct", however I will explain. `rep_total` is the [denormalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) total of all `rep_points` for each user. That trigger automatically keeps the total correct - it fires whenever the base data changes, recalculates the total and updates it. My query does exactly that, without the use of variables (so a stored procedure is not required), but if used would have to be called explicitly by the application (as an extra query) whenever the app changes data in `users_reputation`. The total speed would be only slightly slower.